# OpenCV Mat visulization

Tags: opencv, mat

I was wondering anyone can provide some functions for OpenCV that allows Mat visualization in 3D (2D coordinates plus 1D pixel intensity) which just like function surf does in Matlab.

Comment: OpenCV is not really for plotting.

Comment: Do you mean for debug or for presentation?

Comment: @Miki Yes. I was hoping I can visualize my Gaussian matrix in opencv since I am translating code from Matlab to Opencv and I must make sure they are exactly identical.

Comment: If you're using visual studio use "Image Watch" extension, else just show/write to file your image. If you're on opencv 3.0 or 2.4.11 you can apply a colormap like Matlab, it should be something like cv::applyColorMap(...)

Comment: @Miki Thanks! My current way is save the mat to xml and then import to Matlab then visualize it. Will try the new version of OpenCV and the function applyColorMap. Your answer is very helpful!

Comment: Also, if you want something like Matlab surf in opencv  you can play around with [viz](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/viz/table_of_content_viz/table_of_content_viz.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you use CLion you can use the OpenCV Image Viewer plugin, which displays matrices while debugging with just on click.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14371-opencv-image-viewer

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm an author of this plugin